# How do I make all dialog popups display on secondary monitor?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So I've been learning how to use Adobe Photoshop and I came across a unique problem. At first I thought Photoshop was bugging out and was getting frustrated considering I just bought Adobe Photoshop CC and your required to subscribe for one year (monthly payments). I noticed when I was trying to use image resize and my mouse turned square but the dialog box didn't popup, I kept force closing thinking it was a bug or something. Finally I restarted my computer and told it to NOT reopen windows. I opened photoshop, moved photoshop to my larger secondary monitor and tried again. And there the image dialog box was it had been popping under windows. I am using Adobe Photoshop CC 2017 on macOS and want to know if there is an option I can select to force all dialog popups for photoshop to open on the secondary monitor and not under other windows on my primary monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can control where dialog boxes appear initially, other than to reset them so they all appear on the primary monitor.

For *most* dialog boxes you can drag them to the secondary monitor *after* they pop up. Then when they appear subsequently, they should pop up at the location you moved them to (on the second monitor).

However, there will still be some dialogs that present themselves on the primary monitor. You just have to get used to looking there if you don't see a dialog you expect to see.